# Excel VBA Proper with exceptions

Tags: vba, excel

I use this code to convert names to Proper Case with the exceptions "von", "af", "de". But it doesnt work since the names are often "von Erik" or "af John" not just "von" or "af". How can I make excel get this?

```
Sub ProperCase()

    Dim rng As Range

    'Use special cells so as not to overwrite formula.
    For Each rng In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
        Select Case rng.Value
            Case "von", "af", "de"
                rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbLowerCase)
            Case Else
                'StrConv is the VBA version of Proper.
                rng.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(rng.Value)
        End Select
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead convert the whole cell to Proper Case then run a triple replace function to replace any Proper Case versions of your words:

```
Sub ProperCase()

Dim rng As Range

'Use special cells so as not to overwrite formula.
For Each rng In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Cells
    rng.Value = StrConv(rng.Value, vbProperCase)
    rng.Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(rng.Value, "Von", "von"),"Af","af"), "De", "de")
Next rng

End Sub
```